# JqueryMobile Popup menu is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build an dummy page to understand Jquerymobile but i am not able to implement "Menu" [click on Menu button on the page] working on the link below:

http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

how can I implement? I am using Jquerymobile 1.1.0 version.

Any code sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a beta feature not yet released, I would check to make sure you are using

- jQuery 1.7.1 or later ( http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.js )
- jQM 1.2.0 ( http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.mobile.js )
- jQM 1.2.0 css ( http://jquerymobile.com/test/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css )

Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WSZ5b/1/

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Related:

- [Popups in jQuery Mobile not working as intended, please advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996310/popups-in-jquery-mobile-not-working-as-intended-please-advice)

Comment: Many thanks it worked in first hit. SO Phill, can i download jquerymobile updated doc and updated js files? I downloaded the updated doc from http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/ here but using downloaded js files it is not working. So what should i do to updated my framework?

Comment: @vkwave you can always find the latest here: http://jquerymobile.com/download/ or download the 1.2 branch here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/1.2

Comment: hi @Phill Pafford, Menu popup functionality is not in 1.2 branch. So what should i do to implement it? Please guide.