# Popups in jQuery Mobile not working as intended, please advice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

Popups in jQuery Mobile not working as intended, please advice.

The popup DIV is still visible,one would expect that DIV to be hidden and it doesnt popup when the link is clicked.It seems to work in the demos in jQuery docs.

Is something wrong with the code below?

```
<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup">Pop Up</a>
     <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExample">
     This is a POP UP.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<p>You have entered: <span id="dialogoutput"></span></p>

    <a href="#" id="dialoglink" data-role="button">Open Dialog</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).delegate('#simplestring', 'click', function() {
  $(this).simpledialog({
    'mode' : 'string',
    'prompt' : 'What do you say?',
    'buttons' : {
      'OK': {
        click: function () {
          $('#dialogoutput').text($('#dialoglink').attr('data-string'));
        }
      },
      'Cancel': {
        click: function () { },
        icon: "delete",
        theme: "c"
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Referance:_

http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/string.html

Answer (score 5):

You are using a beta feature not yet released, I would check to make sure you are using

- jQuery 1.7.1 or later ( http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.js )
- jQM 1.2.0 ( http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.mobile.js )
- jQM 1.2.0 css ( http://jquerymobile.com/test/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css )

Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WSZ5b/1/

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Your Code:

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-body">
        <a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup">Pop Up</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExample">
            This is a POP UP.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer mate,since its a beta feature I'm not sure if I should be using the jQM1.2(test).Im working on a project that needs to go live next week.For now I think I will use jQueryMobile SimpleDialog 2.What do you suggest?

Comment: If you're on twitter you can ask the dev's of jQM @jquerymobile when a release date for 1.2.x is? If it's close enough I would keep the popup but if they're a couple of weeks or more before releasing the update I would use the dialog functionality. But it's all relative as there are more unknown variables like, 1- Can you update after releasing the code, What devices are you targeting, when is the release date, etc... Just some other things to think about

Comment: In my case the css was doing all the crazy stuff. upgrading to v1.2 did the trick . thx