# Jquery mobile popup is not working in local file

Tags: jquery-mobile

jquery mobile popup as they described in docs of jquery is not working on my local files. Is there any problem with file which I am running locally. I have included only jquery mobile css, js and jquery js, anything extra need to be included please advice.

Code:

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
 <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div> this code in html shows only text and nothing is happening if I click on open pop up

Comment: and the javascript code?

Comment: Check this Answer: You are attempting a feature of JQM 1.2Beta:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/10998673/322933]

Comment: Yes I have googled in many forums and finally got the answer that it is in a future release of JQM but not the stable version one. thanks all

Comment: Please mark my answer is correct them to help others that find your question helpful as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use features only available in jQuery Mobile 1.2 Alpha. Ensure that you have included this library after you include jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. Make sure to import librariesi n following order. The version I used to check is mentioned inside the braces.

1. jQuery (1.9.1 preferable)
2. jQuery Mobile (1.3.x)
3. Your custom js file

Here is an example <kbd>**[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/Z5c5G/)**</kbd>.

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
</div>
```